# External to OSGI bundle - blueprint.xml file

Tags: java, apache-camel, karaf, blueprint-osgi

Karaf bundle with camel routes defined with blueprint.xml.

Is there a way to make the blueprint.xml configurable, that is, not be part of the bundle jar?

I tried "import resource" but it seems to not be supported by blueprint.
Bundle-Blueprint in the manifest cannot point to a file external to the bundle jar.

The purpose is to be able to change routes dynamically and also have variable number of choice-when content based routing.

The only way that seems to work for me is using java code with RouteBuilder - RouteDefinition, WhenDefinition... and specifying the routes in an external config file.